# Links not working properly within flexbox container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm having trouble simply using links within a flexbox layout. The links actually work (as in if you click it, it will take you to wherever), but the problem is with the cursor.

In Chrome and Safari, the cursor only displays as a pointer for a split-second as you enter the link. In Firefox, the cursor rapidly flashes between the default arrow and a pointer.

CodePen demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vLOVwK

I've tried using `cursor: pointer;` and also wrapping the link in a `<div>` to no avail.

Is this a known bug? (I couldn't find any info on it) and are there any workarounds? Thanks.

**Edit**: I should add that I'm on OSX using the latest versions of Chrome, Safari and FF.

**Edit 2**: Screencast GIF of problem: http://i.imgur.com/6FpuwYI.gifv

Comment: Just tested on Chrome, FF and IE11. No problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
.flex-container {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}
```

You have:

```
   .flex-container {
  -webkit-display: flex;
      -ms-display: flex;
          display: flex;
    }
```

Which AFAIK doesn't work. Btw, I don't think [prefixes are necessary](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) anymore.